# How to add extensions to files in windows 10 directory with git-bash

Tags: windows, bash, git-bash

[image]

I'm working in win 10 with git-bash. I have a number of files listed above with no extension. I'd like to add .jpg extensions to all. I've tried

```
$ for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f%.jpg}"; done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
$ for f in *; do mv "$f" "$f.jpg"; done
```

Your solution is more oriented around removing extensions instead of adding them.

Comment: Thank you very much, a big help

Answer (score 1):

You don't need for `%`

```
$ for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f}.jpg"; done
```

Comment: if you don't mind, I'll accept his answer  - He needs the points more than you, but thank you very much for your time